# Memory Management in a Objective-C static library

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, static-libraries

I'm quite new to the `Objectivce-C` and I was wondering what is the correct way of `memory management` in a **`static library`** without ARC.
Lets say my library has a method that returns `NSString*`:

```
- (NSString *) foo
{
    ...
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"bar"];
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

So as far as I understand, since `foo` allocated the `NSString` it also needs to release it (or queue it for releasing). `NSString` is a return value, so the only thing I can do is to `autorelease` it. This creates a problem: if library is used in a command line tool, the developer needs to know that `foo` needs an `@autoreleasepool` otherwise calling `foo` multiple times inside main `@autoreleasepool` with eat up memory. This seems to me like I'm delegating memory management from library to the app which seems like a terrible thing to do. Is there a better way to do this? Or can I somehow make it obvious for the developer that `foo` needs an `@autoreleasepool`?

Comment: This Q makes no sense if we don't know if you are using ARC or not.

Comment: If he uses `autorelease` within his static library, that obviouly means he doesn't use ARC, doesn't it?

Comment: @Zaphod You would rather assume that someone who doesn't understand at least one part of basic memory management has a thorough understanding of the rest?

Comment: @hooleyhoop no need to be cocky

Comment: @hooleyhoop What I meant was you cannot compile some code containing `autorelease` under ARC, so for me the not use of ARC was obvious. But I understand your point.

Comment: @RytisI no offence intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autorelease pools do not deallocate objects automatically; they need to be manually drained. In Cocoa applications, this is done by the main thread's run loop, so normally most of developers don't have to do anything for that and don't know about it.

However, in any long-running functions, like command-line tool's `main`, or a background thread, it's the programmer's responsibility to manually drain autorelease pool periodically.

You are following the global memory management rules and that's the right thing to do. There's no need to change anything; it's not about ARC or static libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Every thread requires an autoreleasepool*. If your code is called and there is no pool in place then the thread hasn't been set up properly and this is a programmer error.

Unless you created the thread (or process) this isn't your responsibility and has nothing to do with lazy memory management on your behalf.

The reason methods don't indicate that they need an autoreleasepool to be in place is because an autorelease pool always has to be in place.

*Sure you can write Objective-c that doesn't use autorelease, and about which you can reason with almost certainty will never use autorelease when internals change. Such code would only be able to use a small subset of Cocoa, if any, and would likely be pretty terrible.